# How can I use an IComparer<T> to sort by arbitrary values?

Tags: c#, sorting, icomparer

I receive a sorted list of integers which I would like to use to sort a `ListCollectionView` via `ListCollectionView.CustomSort`. This property accepts an `IComparer` and I've created one but, as expected, I can only compare values on generic objects `x` and `y`.

```
public List<int> SortedIds = new List<int> { 13, 7, 5, 3, 1 };
public class Item {
  int Id { get; set; }    
}

public class IdComparer : IComparer<Item> {
  public int Compare(Item x, Item y) {
    // Comparisons 
    // ???
    // return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you could sort any way you wanted, how would you sort it?

Comment: Why is `IdComparer` not an `IComparer<int>`? How is `Item` related to the `SortedIds` list? There's a disconnect here.

Comment: @MattBall The class Item is extremely simplified for this question.  SortedIds actually exist on a separate object and the `Item` does not have access to that. There are many properties on `Item` of value.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's a pretty vague question. I want to sort the `List` of `Item` by their `Id` in the order of `SortedIds`. Again, not sure if that's what you wanted to know.

Comment: @Erode Yes, I did not understand that was your question, that was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare by their index in your `SortedIds` list, you can do:

```
public class IdComparer : IComparer<Item> {
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> idIndexes;
    public IdComparer(IEnumerable<int> sortedIds)
    {
        idIndexes = sortedIds
            .Select((id, idx) => new { Id = id, Index = idx })
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Id, p.Index);
    }

    public int Compare(Item x, Item y) {
        xIndex = idIndexes[x.Id];
        yIndex = idIndexes[y.Id]
        return xIndex.CompareTo(yIndex);
    }
}
```

However you could use linq:

```
IEnumerable<Item> sorted = SortedIds
    .Select((id, idx) => new { Id = id, Index = idx })
    .Join(items, p => i.Id, item => item.Id, (p, item) => new { Item = item, Index = idx })
    .OrderBy(p => p.Index)
    .Select(p => p.Item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to return `SortedIds.IndexOf(x.Id).CompareTo(SortedIds.IndexOf(y.Id))`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343617.aspx) to order by any field you want. Like this:

```
List<Item> sortedById = items.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).ToList();
```

and

```
List<Item> sortedByEgo = items.OrderBy(x=>x.Ego).ToList();
```

(for types that don't compare directly you can also use the variant of OrderBy that takes an IComparer argument, but that's not needed here if Id and Ego are ints).